# Connect a Azure Web App to a company VPN

Tags: azure, vpn

I'd like to connect my Azure Web App (Standard Plan app service), to my work VPN so that it can call web services within the VPN.

I don't have any control over the VPN network so can't install anything there, but I do have VPN IP/Credentials supplied by the network admins.

Can someone tell me if this is possible and how I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a Web App, however you can setup [**Hybrid Connections**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) to use a VM inside your network (or your own computer if we're talking Dev scenario) to reverse proxy requests to those web services. All connections are outbound so no need to tinker with firewalls. Communication between the Web App and the Hybrid Connection Manager is encrypted with TLS 1.2.

> Within the Azure App Service, **Hybrid Connections** can be used to access application resources in other networks. It provides access FROM your app TO an application endpoint. It does not enable an alternative capability to access your application.
>
> As used in the App Service, each hybrid connection correlates to a single TCP host and port combination. This means that the hybrid connection endpoint can be on any operating system and any application provided you are hitting a TCP listening port. Hybrid connections does not know or care what the application protocol is or what you are accessing. It is simply providing network access.

[image: Hybrid Connections]

Comment: I've currently got the Web App connected to an Azure VNET, is it possible to connect the VNET to the VPN, and so giving the Web App the necessary access?

Comment: You'll need to setup a site-to-site IKEv2 VPN for that and terminate the IPsec tunnel at your company's edge router; your networking team may or may not be happy about that - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal